# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing a heatmap to plot a city using an API google Geocoding API. I follow this link [enter link description here](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Python/Automatic+Geocoding+using+Python.html) because I have the same type of data. I activated the API in Google Developer page and I created a key to use it. I run the code separatly using notebook jupyter.

First block it running well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import googlemaps
import gmaps

API_KEY = 'Geocoding API' 
gm = googlemaps.Client(key='key api ......')
```

Second block run successfuly:

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False)
data = data.fillna('')                   # fill empty entries with ''
print(list(data))                        # print Variable Name
data.head()
```

third block it running well also:

```
def Geocode(query):
    # do geocoding
    try:
        geocode_result = gm.geocode(query)[0]       
        latitude = geocode_result['geometry']['location']['lat']
        longitude = geocode_result['geometry']['location']['long']
        return latitude,longitude
    except IndexError:
        return 0

def GeocodeStreetLocationCity(data):
    lat=[]                            # initialize latitude list
    lng=[]                            # initialize longitude list
    start = data.index[0]             # start from the first data
    end = data.index[maxRow-1]        # end at maximum number of row
    for i in range(start,end+1,1):    # iterate all rows in the data
        isSuccess=True                # initial Boolean flag
        query = data.lat[i] + ' ' + data.long[i]  # try set up our query street-location-city 
        result=Geocode(query)
        if result==0:         # if not successful,
            query = data.lat[i] + ' ' + data.long[i]                     # try set up another query location-city
            result=Geocode(query)
            if result==0:     # if still not successful,
                query =  data.lat[i] + ' ' + data.long[i]                  # try set up another query street-city
                result=Geocode(query)
                if Geocode(query)==0: # if still not successful,
                    isSuccess=False                                           # mark as unsuccessful
                    print(i, 'is failed')
                else:
                    print(i, result)
            else:
                print(i, result)
        else:
            print(i, result)
        if isSuccess==True:           # if geocoding is successful,
            # store the results
            lat.append(result[0])     # latitude
            long.append(result[1])     # longitude
    return lat,long
```

I got the error in the last block when I run it:

```
# call the geocoding function
[lat,long]=GeocodeStreetLocationCity(data)

# we put the list of latitude,longitude into pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'latitude': lat,
     'longitude': long
    })
```

The error is:

When I run my code it return an error in the last block:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-67-d174cb0d8b65> in <module>
          1 # call the geocoding function
    ----> 2 [lat,long]=GeocodeStreetLocationCity(data)         


    ---> 18         query = data.lat[i] + ' ' + data.long[i]  # try set up our query street-location-city        

    TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

I think that I have a numpy array of strings, not floats. This is what is meant by dtype('

Some one can suggest me a solution please ?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the output of `data.head()`.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 edited my question

Comment: Please check if there are strings in `data.lat` or `data.long`.

Comment: The error is trying to concatenate strings. See the `' '`.  But items are numpy arrays of strings, not python strings.

Comment: This works if `data.lat[i]` is a string.  You will get this error if it is an array of strings, i.e. several lat/long values per row of `data`.  If you want more help, you need to show `data.head()` for the problem case.

Comment: I can't run your code, an so can't perform any diagnostic prints, such as displaying `data.lat[i]` to identify its type (and shape and dtype).  You have to do that exploration if you want more help.